# Is there a way I can shorten this list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Can you help me shorten this python code involving list comprehensions? In my current code, the variable `e_col` is not utilized. What I don't know yet is how can I utilize this `e_col` variable. Here's the code:

```
e_rows = (10,34)
e_col = (4,6,8,10,13,15,17,19)
inst = 'A'

test_list = [inst+'_r'+str(e_rows[0])+'c'+str(i) for i in range(4,12,2)]
test_list.extend([inst+'_r'+str(e_rows[0])+'c'+str(i) for i in range(13,21,2)])
test_list.extend([inst+'_r'+str(e_rows[1])+'c'+str(i) for i in range(4,12,2)])
test_list.extend([inst+'_r'+str(e_rows[1])+'c'+str(i) for i in range(13,21,2)])

print(test_list)
```

When I ran this code, it returns:

```
['A_r10c4', 'A_r10c6', 'A_r10c8', 'A_r10c10', 'A_r10c13', 'A_r10c15', 'A_r10c17', 'A_r10c19', 'A_r34c4', 'A_r34c6', 'A_r34c8', 'A_r34c10', 'A_r34c13', 'A_r34c15', 'A_r34c17', 'A_r34c19']
```

I also looked into `itertools.product` but I can't understand how it works.

Comment: Could you describe a bit of what's actually going on here? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: I got my intended results list, like I have shown in the above description. I want to shorten the code and to utilize the `e_col` tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list comprehension can do "product" with nested loops, pure Python, no libs

```
test_list = [inst+'_r'+str(j)+'c'+str(i) for j in e_rows for i in e_col]
```

Comment: Thanks. This one of yours is very neat in the code.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the basic structure of your elements is:

```
'A_r{}c{}'  # {} are the placeholders for str.format
```

Then you just need the row and column numbers, for which [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) certainly seems like a good bet:

```
from itertools import product

test_list = ['A_r{}c{}'.format(row, col) for row, col in product(e_rows, e_col)]
```

Which gives the same output:

```
>>> test_list
['A_r10c4', 'A_r10c6', 'A_r10c8', 'A_r10c10', 'A_r10c13', 'A_r10c15', 'A_r10c17', 'A_r10c19', 'A_r34c4', 'A_r34c6', 'A_r34c8', 'A_r34c10', 'A_r34c13', 'A_r34c15', 'A_r34c17', 'A_r34c19']
```

It's not clear why you used two `range`s rather than just `e_col`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the one liner code. However, in real application, `A` in the resulting list is also a variable (i.e `inst`). How can I modify your answer to take that into consideration?

Comment: @Meeyaw that's a pretty simple tweak, I'm sure you can manage that without further help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks by the way. And yes, i know how to tweak that. Thanks again.